# Search an 80 GB text file using strings in another and save the results for each string to separate files

Tags: php, regex, string, awk, grep

I have a massive 80 GB file that I need to search using strings in another smaller text file and (here is the kicker) I need to then save the results for each matching line to separate files named with the search string.

What would be the most efficient way to handle this task with PHP or AWK?

Example lines:

Original 80 GB text file:

```
line1 "value001","value002","Value003"
line2 "Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"
line3 "value001","value002","Value003"
line4 "value001","value002","Value003"
line5 "value001","value002","Value003"
line6 "Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"
line7 "value010","value022","Value009"
```

Search string text file `search.txt` contains these values:

```
Value003
Value007
Value009
```

Three text files would result containing all the matching lines for each search string:

```
Value003.txt would contain lines 1, 3, 4, 5
Value007.txt would contain lines 2 and 6
Value009.txt would contain line 7
```

Additional clarification:
To be exact the strings are lists of domains and phone numbers like:

```
joes.com
brick.net
moes.com
sams.net 
2125551212 
2025551212
(202)555-1212
```

Currently, I am doing the search using a long regex string in textpad like this:

```
brick.net|joes.com|moes.com|sams.net|2125551212|2025551212|(202)555-1212
```

That search is both cumbersome, slow, and results in a fair amount of false positives like "sams network" and "yellow brick network".

I am trying to capture fielded values like sam@sam.net but not "sams network".

Comment: The example suggests that the search string and the comma-separated value must be identical for there to be a "match".  If that is the case, then please indicate as much, as small details such as this can make a big performance difference (and therefore a difference in recommendations) when large files are involved.

Comment: Can a line ever contain multiple matches, i.e., should go into multiple result files?

Comment: hey peak!

To be exact the strings are lists of domains and phone numbers like:
joes.com
brick.net
moes.com
sams.net
2125551212
2025551212
(202)555-1212

Currently I am doing the search using a long regex string in textpad like this:
brick.net|joes.com|moes.com|sams.net|2125551212|2025551212|(202)555-1212

That search is both cumbersome, slow, and results in a fair amount of false positives like "sams network" and "yellow brick network". 

I am trying to capture fielded values like sam@sam.net but not "sams network".

Comment: @benjamin Yes it is possible for a line to have multiple matches. Does that present a problem?

Comment: No, just means that my awk solution can't prematurely exit the for loop. You should add that to the question (and indent your code lines with 4 spaces so they get the proper markup).

Comment: Don't show us one sample input and then say "just kidding it's not really that, it's this" and then list a bunch of different values. Edit your question to simply show us concise, testable, truly representative sample input and expected output. If one line can have multiple values that match, show that. If one search string can be a substring of another, show that. If the search strings can contain RE metacharacters, show that. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bash and grep

Looping over the search file and grepping for each line, redirecting the result to the properly named file:

```
while read str; do grep -F "$str" infile > "$str".txt; done < search.txt
```

where `infile` is your large file. This results in the following files:

```
==> Value003.txt <==
line1"value001","value002","Value003"
line3"value001","value002","Value003"
line4"value001","value002","Value003"
line5"value001","value002","Value003"

==> Value007.txt <==
line2"Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"
line6"Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"

==> Value009.txt <==
line7"value010","value022","Value009"
```

Notice that this processes the very large file multiple times, and even though grep is fast, looping over a file with Bash is slow, so this is only viable if `search.txt` is relatively small.

#### Awk

To process the large file only once, you could iterate over it with awk, and for each line check if any of the strings match:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Read search file into array
NR == FNR {
    searchstr[$0]
    next
}

{
    # Iterate over search strings
    for (str in searchstr) {
        # Print to file if matches
        if (index($0, str)) {
            print $0 > str ".txt"
            # next  # Uncomment if only one search string can occur per line
            # close(str ".txt") # Uncomment if there are too many open files
        }
    }
}
```

This has to be called as follows:

```
awk -f script.awk search.txt infile
```

In a less readable one-line version:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ss[$0];next}{for(s in ss)if(index($0,s))print$0>s".txt"}' search.txt infile
```

Notice that some awks have a limit to the number of open filehandles<sup>1</sup>, and others (GNU awk) can manage more but slow down beyond that limit – this depends on the size of your `search.txt`. If it becomes a problem, we can add `close(str ".txt")` to the `if` clause to close the file after each write.

If only one search string can occur on each line, we can uncomment the `next` statement in the loop.

---

<sup>1</sup> The original awk had a limit of 15 open files!

Comment: Ben thank you for the quick reply...

The search.txt file has about 200 strings so is grep my only option?

Comment: @trackthis If you have GNU awk, I'd try the awk solution first. Even with other awks, but include the `close` statement mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is really as shown then all you need with GNU awk is:

```
NR==FNR{s=(s ? s "|" : "") $0; next} match($0,s,a){print > (a[0] ".txt")}
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{s=(s ? s "|" : "") $0; next} match($0,s,a){print $0 "\t> " (a[0] ".txt")}' search.txt bigfile
line1"value001","value002","Value003"   > Value003.txt
line2"Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"        > Value007.txt
line3"value001","value002","Value003"   > Value003.txt
line4"value001","value002","Value003"   > Value003.txt
line5"value001","value002","Value003"   > Value003.txt
line6"Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"        > Value007.txt
line7"value010","value022","Value009"   > Value009.txt
```

If that doesn't work because your input isn't really as shown in your question then, obviously, edit your question to show some more accurately representative sample input and output.

Comment: Ed, thank you for the answer...I have added in additional info of my representational example.